# Displaying a QT Widget on / overlaying a 3rd Party Window (in Windows)

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, overlay, hook

This is not something I have tried before and am a complete newbie to the likes of HWND, hooking etc.

Basically, I would like to display / overlay a QT Widget on top of a window of a 3rd party application (which I have no control over, I only know very basic information like window title / caption and its class name) and I have absolutely no idea how one would go about this. I also want the QT Widget to remain in it relative location to the window of the 3rd party application, even if that window is moved around the screen.

Answer (score 6):

### WinAPI part

1. Use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to obtain HWND of the target window.
2. Use [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain current position of the window.

### Qt part

1. Make your top level `QWidget` or `QMainWindow` frameless and make it to stay on top using [window flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowType-enum) `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` and `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`.
2. Make it transparent using [attribute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`.
3. Setup a `QTimer` to request window rect periodically and adjust the widget position.

### Example code (tested)

Add in header:

```
private:
  HWND target_window;

private slots:
  void update_pos();
```

Source:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
  // example of target window class: "Notepad++"
  target_window = FindWindowA("Notepad++", 0); 
  if (!target_window) {
    qDebug() << "window not found";
    return;
  }
  QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update_pos()));
  timer->start(50); // update interval in milliseconds 
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
  delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::update_pos() {
  RECT rect;
  if (GetWindowRect(target_window, &rect)) {
    setGeometry(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, 
                rect.bottom - rect.top);
  } else {
    //maybe window was closed
    qDebug() << "GetWindowRect failed";
    QApplication::quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: I finally getting around to trying your suggestion, what I find happens is Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint, results in the QT window of course always being on top, but also allows a 3rd window to be moved inbetween.

How would I go about modifying this code, such that the overlay just overlays the identified winapi window, and should a 3rd window be dragged over the target window with QT overlay, it is that which sits on top…and vice verse..i.e the QT overlay is in z order always rendered exactky one layer above the target window.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's not possible.